# Как связать файл отчета с Jasper под Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, jasperreports, java

Пишу на Java с использованием Spring MVC. Хочу создать файл отчета в формате PDF(именно файл, а не форму). В WEB-INF у меня лежит папка `jrxml` c `report.jrxml`. Использую Jasper, но не могу связать Jasper c этим файлом. В команде

```
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("/jrxml/report.jrxml")
```

получаю ошибку "файл не найден". Подозреваю, что надо как-то property настроить, но как? Я в Spring, можно сказать, чайник. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Попробовала полное имя задать: `"http:\localhost:8080\myApp\WEB-INF\jrxml\report.jrxml"`, ошибка: "неверный синтаксис имени файла, папки или носителя".

Answer (score 1):

> Попробовала полное имя задать: "http:\localhost:8080\myApp\WEB-INF\jrxml  \report.jrxml", ошибка: "неверный синтаксис имени файла, папки или носителя".

Ну, тут точно нужно не url, а путь к файлу в файловой системе.

**Обновление**

Попробуйте такой хак, напишите в коде строчки:

```
 File file = new File("");
 System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Таким образом узнаете, в какой директории находитесь. Можно ещё попробовать так:

```
jasperReport =  JasperCompileManager.compileReport("classpath:jrxml/report.jrxml")
```

или так:

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReport("classpath:report.jrxml")
```

**Обновление 2**

Если дело будет на сервере, то будет указан путь, где лежит приложение на сервере. Попробуйте дополнить путь, который выводит та конструкция до места, где лежит файл с отчетом.

**Обновление 3**

Конечно. Ваш проект ведь тоже на сервере, только на локальном. Точно также будет и там. Можете поэкспериментировать с этим, собрав war файл и положив его в директорию вашего локального веб-сервера, на котором запускаете приложение. Деплой это уже отдельная задача в общем-то.

**Обновление 4**

Томкат в Идее не будет его кидать в папку томката, поэтому на С: да. Поэтому можете попробовать собрать war, как я уже сказал и положить в директорию томката, в папку webapps, запустить томкат, и попробовать просто из браузера проделать необходимые действия.

Comment: Это я поняла, но как задать на сервере в файловой системе правильно? Я уже  все варианты попробовала, но файл не находится. Начинала и с MyApp, и с WEB-INF. Не находит никак.

Comment: Попробовала узнать, где нахожусь, и оказалось, что нахожусь вовсе не на сервере, а в папке своего проекта на С:. А как же я буду создавать файл отчета? Он значит тоже в моем проекте создастся? А если дело на настоящем сервере будет, то где же будет файл создаваться? Как мне его правильно создать, чтобы не было проблем при переносе на сервер?

Comment: То есть он будет тогда тоже в проекте находиться, только уже в том, который будет раздеплоин на сервер? И я там спокойно могу также создавать файлы и папки?

Comment: Я его сейчас из IntelJIdea запускаю, с помощью плагина для Томката. Поэтому, может, он на С: оказывается, а не в Томкатной папке, куда собственно приложение должно деплоиться?

Comment: Не получилось ничего, файл создается в папке пользователя, а не в tomcate. Где же он на настоящем сервере создастся?